# php mysql total sum two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sum

When someone selects a service number, then it will pop down and only give the total one records. I want it to give to total from two tables..

```
<?php

   $qry = mysql_query ("SELECT SUM(fruit) AS total FROM fruitinventory WHERE `fruitcolor` LIKE '%{$_POST['select']}%'");

$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);


    echo $row['total'];

?>

<?php

   $qry = mysql_query ("SELECT SUM(fruitsmart) AS total FROM fruitrotten WHERE `fruitcolor` LIKE '%{$_POST['select']}%'");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);


    echo $row['total'];

?>
```

Then

I want the total of both rows to display then too.

```
<?php 

$total return = $row+$row2 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consolidate your two database calls into a single query, and use the columns of the result as your variables to echo out:

```
<?php
    $input = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['select']);
    $sql = "
        SELECT
            (
                SELECT SUM(fruit) 
                FROM fruitinventory 
                WHERE fruitcolor LIKE '%$input%'
            ) AS totalfruit,
            (
                SELECT SUM(fruitsmart) 
                FROM fruitrotten 
                WHERE fruitcolor LIKE '%$input%'
            ) AS totalfruitsmart";
    $qry = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);

    echo $row['totalfruit'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['totalfruitsmart'] . '<br />';
    echo $row['totalfruit'] + $row['totalfruitsmart'];
?>
```

Please, at the very minimum, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to help prevent against SQL injection attacks which is what your original code was wide open to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep that same sort of structure for you code, you can display a total like so (Note: MySQLi (i = improved) functions should be used as MySQL functions are [deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799)):

```
<?php

$qry = mysqli_query ("SELECT SUM(fruit) AS total FROM fruitinventory WHERE `fruitcolor` LIKE '%{$_POST['select']}%'");
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);
echo $row2['total'];


$qry = mysqli_query ("SELECT SUM(fruitsmart) AS total FROM fruitrotten WHERE `fruitcolor` LIKE '%{$_POST['select']}%'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);
echo $row['total'];

$total = $row['total'] + $row2['total'];
echo $total;

?>
```

Since it will come up, I suggest you look at using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of the mysql_ (or at least wrap [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) around your variables) to protect your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the sum using only SQL. Something like below:

```
$qry = mysql_query ("

    SELECT (

        ( SELECT SUM(fruit) AS total FROM fruitinventory WHERE `fruitcolor` LIKE '%{$_POST['select']}%' ) + 

        ( SELECT SUM(fruitsmart) AS total FROM fruitrotten WHERE `fruitcolor` LIKE '%{$_POST['select']}% )

    ) AS total") ;

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);

echo $row['total'];
```